# Why is my program printing out only the last object value of the array?

Tags: java, arrays, traversal

Candidate class:

```
public class Candidate 
{
    private static String name;
    private static int numVotes;

    Candidate(String name, int numVotes)
    {
        Candidate.name = name;
        Candidate.numVotes = numVotes;
    }

    public String toString()
    {
        return name + " recieved " + numVotes + " votes.";
    }

    public static int getVotes()
    {
         return numVotes;
    }

    public static void setVotes(int inputVotes)
    {
         numVotes = inputVotes;
    }

    public static String getName()
    {
        return name;
    }

    public static void setName(String inputName)
    {
        name = inputName;
    }
}
```

TestCandidate class:

```
public class TestCandidate 
{
    public static Candidate[] election = new Candidate[5];

    public static void addCandidates(Candidate[] election)
    {
        election[0] = new Candidate("John Smith", 5000);
        election[1] = new Candidate("Mary Miller", 4000);
        election[2] = new Candidate("Michael Duffy", 6000);
        election[3] = new Candidate("Tim Robinson", 2500);
        election[4] = new Candidate("Joe Ashton", 1800);
    }


    public static int getTotal(Candidate[] election)
    {
        int total = 0;

        for (Candidate i : election)
        {
            total += Candidate.getVotes();
        }

        return total;
    }

    public static void printResults(Candidate[] election)
    {
        System.out.printf("%s%12s%25s", "Candidate", "Votes", "Percentage of Votes\n");

        for (Candidate i: election)
        {
            System.out.printf("\n%s%10s%10s", Candidate.getName(), Candidate.getVotes(), ((double)Candidate.getVotes()/getTotal(election) * 100));
        }

        System.out.println("\n\nTotal Number of Votes: " + getTotal(election));
    } 

    public static void main (String args[])
    {
        addCandidates(election);
        printResults(election);
    }
}
```

Whenever I run the TestCandidate class, it outputs this:

```
Candidate       Votes     Percentage of Votes

Joe Ashton      1800      20.0
Joe Ashton      1800      20.0
Joe Ashton      1800      20.0
Joe Ashton      1800      20.0
Joe Ashton      1800      20.0

Total Number of Votes: 9000
```

The point of the program is to output all of the candidates and calculate averages based on everyone. I believe it's an issue within my for-each loops. Any help with this would be appreciated.

Comment: Likely because your private variables in `Candidate` class are static

Comment: `static` means you want to have variables which shared across all instances.  If you are setting `static`` fields in your constructor it is almost certainly a bug.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
private static String name;
private static int numVotes;
```

static members have one value for all the instances of the class. Remove the static keyword in order for different instances to have different values.

Answer (score -2):

If you do this:

```
private static String name;
private static int numVotes;
```

every new `Candidate` object you create will overwrite the fields `name` and `numVotes` of ALL other objects because these fields are not objects fields are class fields...

you need to remove the static keyword of those fields in order to work:

### Example:

```
public class Candidate 
{
    private String name;
    private int numVotes;

    Candidate(String name, int numVotes)
    {
        Candidate.name = name;
        Candidate.numVotes = numVotes;
    }
    .... .... ETC ETC
```